# Python + GTK - Scrolled menu bugged

Tags: linux, python-2.7, gtk, pygtk

Basically, when we click on a combobox near to the bottom edge of the screen, the first item of the menu begins at the same vertical position of the combobox, leaving a blank space on top of this.
This way the menu is created with the size to hold all the menu items, but since the first element of these is not put at the top of the menu, the menu has to scroll to see them.

Link to the image: http://postimg.org/image/767ukjphz/

It's not a bug in my code. The menu is created correctly. The bug is in the GTK libraries.

So, what do you suggest me?, how can I resolve this situation?, maybe moving to menu position?